# Excel Formula: Sum all cells in range but when cell is > 10 add 10

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, worksheet-function

Ok I am trying to SUM 5 cells but when the number in a cell is greater than 10 add 10

Example:

```
A1: 10
B1: 9
C1: 13
D1: 10
E1: 11
```

Answer: would be 49 because 10 + 9 + 10 + 10 + 10

The formula I am currently using is =SUMIF(A1:E1, "<= 10") + COUNTIF(A1:E1, ">10")*10

I was wondering if there is a simpler way of doing this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume the COUNTIF should be multiplied by 10, i.e. =SUMIF(A1:E1, "<= 10") + COUNTIF(A1:E1, ">10")*10

Comment: =SUMIF(A1:E1, "<= 10") + COUNTIF(A1:E1, ">10")*10 was actually what I was using sorry

Comment: An additional column(or row) to round down to 10 if greater than ten is an easier formula, but you may not have real estate in the spreadsheet for that.

Comment: I agree would be easier with a helper column but I am changing a corporate spreadsheet. I was done by hand before :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've got about the best approach anyway, unless you want an "array formula"

`=SUM(IF(A1:E1>10,10,A1:E1))`

confirmed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

Comment: Thanks, I might use this because it looks a little cleaner. Glad I wasn't missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the best way to go about this problem is to simply fill A2 with =IF(A1<10, A1, 10) and drag that down. After that, simply do an auto-sum at the bottom of that column.

Comment: I want to do this on over 100 rows. This would double the size of the spreadsheet. I also have to find the remainder but I left that out because SUM(A1:E1) - (Other Equation) will work.